# Adding a check to find if returned value is not an object

Tags: linux, bash, shell, curl, jq

I have a variable that retrieves value as below:

```
val = $(curl command ...)
```

`val` returns an object which looks as `{"parm1":"****","data":"adfsdfsdaf"}`

I want to add a validation for two conditions:

- `val` is either an object  or
- `val.data` is `null`

I want to print a message "data not parsed correctly"

- when `val` is an `object` such as `{"parm1":"****","data":"adfsdfsdaf"}`

I want to print a message "data is null"

- when `val` is an `null`.

I have written below logic for it but it is not looking correct:

```
if [[ ${val} == null ]]; then
  echo "data not parsed correctly"
  exit 1
```

The correct value of `val` is `adfsdfsdaf` when the script should not exit.

Comment: Aside from your syntactically incorrect assignment: Define what you mean by _object_. In bash, the only data type is a string (and, in restricted way, indexed arrays and associative arrays). Also, explain your idea of a _null_. In your code, you just test whether the string stored in `val` equals the string `null`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [jq](/questions/tagged/jq)

```bash
if val=$(curl ... \
         | jq 'try 
                 if .data != null 
                   then . 
                   else ("is null" | halt_error) 
                 end 
               catch
                 ("not an object" | halt_error)
            ' 2>&1
        )
then
    do_something_with_valid "$val"
else
    echo "error: $val" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```